# Why is linear regression wrong for pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, linear-regression

I kept getting wrong answers so I tried it on something very, very basic, and it was still wrong.

```py
input file:
1 1:1
2 1:2
3 1:3
4 1:4
```

```py
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

# Load training data
training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("stupid.txt")

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=100, regParam=0.3, loss='squaredError')

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
print("Coefficients: %s" % str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: %s" % str(lrModel.intercept))

# Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
trainingSummary.residuals.show()
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

Should have gotten coefficients [1] and intercept 0.
Instead got

```py
Coefficients: [0.7884394856681294]
Intercept: 0.52890128583
```

Comment: Can you print the training dataframe, just to make sure it read the file in the way you expected?  I wonder if it isn’t using the correct column as the label.

Comment: The more I look at it, it seems as though it’s trying to output a value of 1 for the given inputs [1,2,3,4].  Did you mean to have your label column be 1 every time?

Comment: @BobSwain it's exactly as I pasted above, that's the file "stupid.txt".  Note that the format is how it has to be, 1: indicates the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the regParam parameter that you’re using.  If I run it with that set to 0, which causes normal OLS to take place, we get the expected output:

Code:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
    (2.0, Vectors.dense(2.0)),
    (3.0, Vectors.dense(3.0)),
    (4.0, Vectors.dense(4.0))], ["label", "features"])

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=100, regParam=0, loss='squaredError')

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
print("Coefficients: %s" % str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: %s" % str(lrModel.intercept))

# Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
trainingSummary.residuals.show()
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients: [1.0]
Intercept: 0.0
numIterations: 1
objectiveHistory: [0.0]
+---------+
|residuals|
+---------+
|      0.0|
|      0.0|
|      0.0|
|      0.0|
+---------+

RMSE: 0.000000
r2: 1.000000
```

It seems like the regParam > 0 is being used as an L2 regularization term, and preventing the model from performing a normal OLS process.